# Issue with JQuery Function Formatting and sum or 2 text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".toCalculate").blur(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $(".toCalculate").formatCurrency(function (index, item) {
                temp = parseFloat($(item).val());
                if (isNaN(temp))
                    temp = 0;
                total = total + temp;
            });
            $(".total").val(total.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is enter in the number with formatting within each textbox and then I want to get the sum of which will be the total of all the textboxes.  What am I doing wrong here.  I thought I pretty much had it but all I am getting for an output is 0.00.  Whats wrong here is the .total that is not giving the right output.  What can I do to fix this so it works correctly?  Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you want this:

**HTML:**

```
<input class="toCalculate" /><br/>
<input class="toCalculate" /><br/>
<input class="toCalculate" /><br/>
<input class="toCalculate" /><br/>
<hr/>
<input class="total">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".toCalculate").on("blur", function(){    
    var total = 0;
    $(".toCalculate").each(function (index, item) {
        var temp = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/[,$]/g,""));
        if (isNaN(temp))
            temp = 0;
        total = total + temp;
    }).formatCurrency();
    $(".total").val(total.toFixed(2)).formatCurrency(); 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/C448Z/1/

Comment: Yes, but the total I would like to be formatted as well and I am still getting 0.00 for total.  What can I do to get the total to be formatted and have the actual sum come out as e.g. $1,000,000.00?

Comment: I have that down but I want to add the formatting.  Is this even possible?

Comment: This unfortunately did not work either.  I am still getting 0.00 for total.  I think my problem exists in the return value, here:  $(".total").val(total.toFixed(2));

Comment: problem is the fact parseFloat("$") is not a number. The issue was my regular expression was wrong. It was looking for "$", not "$ or ,". Changed it

Comment: This is still not working correctly.  I am not sure what to do.  I may just leave it without any formatting.  I can't seem to get the total to return the value.  The value is always 0.00.  I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You are da man.  Thank you so much.  I could not figure that out for the life of me.  This is such a better work around than trying to parse this out in C#.  Thanks again my friend.